# If i have an Event Receiver inside my SharePoint 2013 ,, is it suppose to work in sharepoint 2016 as-is

Tags: 2013, event-receivers, solution-package, 2016, farm-solution

I am created many Event Receivers inside SharePoint server on-premise 2013. using the following technologies:

1. visual studio 2012.
2. the event receivers mainly got executed when list items are updated, created on Wiki Pages and custom lists.

now my question if my current `.wsp` files can work as-is inside sharepoint server 2016 ? or i need to create new `.wsp` files using Visual studio 2015 and related tools??
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason it should not work, unless there are problems with your code itself. Once a solution package has been deployed, your event receivers are applied to the list or library directly: there is nothing in the upgrade process that would reapply your solution package.

You can view a list of the Event Receivers currently installed using the PowerShell script below:

`$url = "http://yoursiteurl"
$title = "YourListTitle"
$web = Get-SPWeb $url
$list = $web.Lists[$title]
$list.EventReceivers`

Comment: i am not talking about upgrading my farm from 2013 to 2016.. i have 2 separate farms for different customers. one customer is using 2013 the other is using 2016 .. now i have an event receiver working well inside 2013, and i want to deploy the same event receiver inside 2016,, so will my wsp which i deploy inside 2013 work as-is inside 2016?? i mean will the same .wsp file work on 2013 and on 2016 ??

Comment: Oh, I see. Still, the wsp architecture hadn't changed; you shouldn't have a problem there. The only potential issue would be in your code itself, and even there I can't think of any serious risks.

Comment: so the maximum risk will be that the event receiver will not work in SP 2016 is this correct ? or there could be other under the cover risks,, if i try to deploy a wsp (which i am using inside SP 2013) inside our new SP 2016 ??

Comment: I cannot think of any risk to your environment at all.

Answer (score 1):

We upgraded our SP2013 to SP2016. The most of our WSPs werent upgraded and all of them work as expected.

Comment: i am not talking about upgrading from 2013 to 2016 ... i have 2 separate farms for different customers. one customer is using 2013 the other is using 2016 .. now i have an event receiver working well inside 2013, and i want to deploy the same event receiver inside 2016,, so will my wsp which i deploy inside 2013 work as-is inside 2016?? i mean will the same .wsp file work on 2013 and on 2016 ??

Comment: yes i think so. it is not relevant if there are two seperate farms or not. i did install my wsp seperate too. once in sharepoint 2013 server and once in 2016. it worked as expected

Comment: If you are not sure to install the wsp at your other customer, you can simply migrate the VS Project to SP 2016. It takes about 5 minutes and we had no problems with migrating solutins yet.