# Event Receiver Compatibility

Tags: 2010, event-receivers, 2016

We are running SharePoint 2010 and I have a request to create a Event Receiver in Visual Studio.

Since we are going to migrate to 2016 in the next year or so, I am wondering about compatibility.

Will my Event Receivers work with 2016?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the event receivers will work as expected in 2016.

Hope this link can confirm the same - [If i have an Event Receiver inside my SharePoint 2013 ,, is it suppose to work in sharepoint 2016 as-is](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/212559/if-i-have-an-event-receiver-inside-my-sharepoint-2013-is-it-suppose-to-work-i)